# Unable to open a cgns file

Tags: gfortran, cgns

Okey, this is not a core programming question; it is more of a question regarding cgns (CFD general notational system) API.

I've exported a grid/mesh file from ANSYS Fluent (which was first created in Gambit 2.46), and I wrote a very simple Fortran program to open and close it (doing nothing else). To check the file is not corrupt I plotted it in Tecplot.

So, when I compiled using gfortran with the mentioned cgns and ran the program I got this error (as part of cg_error_exit_f())

**ADF_Database_Open:File does not exist or is not a HDF5 file**

Here is the program

```
program cavity
include "/usr/include/cgnslib_f.h"
call cg_open_f("Cavity.cgns",CG_MODE_READ,index_file,ier)
!check for error if so exit
if (ier .ne. CG_OK) then
call cg_error_exit_f()
end if
write(*,*)"I kind of opened the file?"
call cg_close_f(index_file,ier)
stop
end program cavity
```

I'm able to write both structured and unstructured grids in cgns format, without any problem.

I suspect the cgns library I'm using(version 2.5.5 packaged in Fedora 15 and Scientific linux 6.1) is built to support only HDF5, while the exported grid file is written in ADF format.

Any ideas to circumvent this or perhaps adding ADF? Which by the way is not packaged in both the distributions. Any other grid generator which is compatible with cgns version 2.5.5?

I hope I was clear. Any further info required, I would provide.

Comment: You have to give me the link which you got at the paste bin site in order for me to see the file you left there.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much that could've gone wrong in here, and I'm afraid you didn't exactly narrow the problem down.

You said you exported a file from Fluent (what kind of a file is it? Be sure!). **cg_error_exit_f()** gave you an error listed. I'm assuming you have the source of the mentioned routines? In the program you include a cgnslib_f.h file - what's in it? I'm assumming the program compiled without errors of any kind, making this a file format question, not a fortran question.

Again, verify what kind of file Fluent produced.

Comment: yeah it is a fileformat question,specifically cgns API question (more specific to version 2.5.5), yeah as i mentioned the file Cavity.cgns is being verified,as i was able to visualise the mesh (in Computational mechanics the discretization of the domain of problem interest) more about cgns here [link](http://cgns.sourceforge.net/) and here [link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGNS) and yes the compilation went without any problem , i formed the executable and ran it.

Comment: the header file cgnslib_f.h included contains the functions and subroutines and some data which provides a way to read and write the data in cgns format(infact its the API) and I'm quite sure From Fluent i exported this file as .cgns (standard extension)

Comment: @Vasu - Okey, let's see what's wrong with it then. Since I assume you have access to what cg_error_exit_f() is doing, could you try to find the above mentioned line ("ADF_database_open ..." something) and check around it to see what's it complaining about? If you want to you can paste that part of the code on some paste site or introduce it here, and I'll try to figure out what I can.

Comment: @Vasu - To accelerate this a bit, if you're online go to chat to room 7256278

Comment: very few questions are linked with CGNS tag , but i hope many fortran guys would know about it (as fortran is heavily used in CFD) so i added gfortran tag.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this situation, I discovered the following tools:
hdf2adf
adf2hdf

They are in the cgns-convert package on Ubuntu and are probably available for your distribution as well.